# Android application creation in eclipse stuck

Tags: android

I am brend new to android application and eclipse. 
I've tried to create my first android app like "hello world" and make few simple steps to create a project with one activity, but Eclipse stuck on the last step.
Here the sample:
[image]
[image]
http://youtu.be/BuIpMp3pJ74
What I do wrong?
I'm using window XP.

Comment: `Eclipse Struck` what happend? where is the logcat

Comment: If you're new to Android development, I'd suggest you should be using Android Studio, not Eclipse. It's now the [official](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html) IDE for Android. I realise that Windows XP is below the minimum requirement for Android Studio, but then the latest Eclipse [isn't tested or validated on Windows older than Windows 7](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/development/readme_eclipse_4.4.html#TargetOperatingEnvironments), either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what you did wrong. You are now using an O.S that even Microsoft do not want. And also, as of now, Google has announced their official IDE for Android, ie Android Studio. It's late time that you switch to a better O.S and the Android studio.